# How do you determine the Pull Direction for a GROMACS umbrella sampling simulation to generate the most accurate free energy value?

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am trying to calculate the free energy between a protein and aptamer using GROMACS. Literature has indicated that one of the best way to do so is by performing an umbrella sampling MD simulation that involves a non-equilibrium pulling simulation that pulls the protein and aptamer apart. I have been running these simulations on certain protein-aptamer complexes but some of the free energy values that I am getting do not match the experimental free energy values from biology experiments. I am thinking that perhaps the pulling direction that I chose was not the best pulling direction. How do I determine the best/correct pulling direction?

I am essentially using the procedure in this tutorial http://www.mdtutorials.com/gmx/umbrella/index.html by Justin A. Lemkul, Ph.D., Virginia Tech Department of Biochemistry, except I am performing it on a protein-aptamer complex.

Comment: You have essentially requested an exhaustive literature review; you are unlikely to get one for free with high quality by just asking on a random online website. As a quantifiable metric, you have three question marks in your post, while official policy here is to ask [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). In your position I would ask whether your xNA-protein force field really can quantitatively predict binding free energies, and whether your sample size is large enough and your pulling _rate_ slow enough.

Comment: I removed questions 2 and 3.